# Get the column names used in calculated column using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I have a calculated column which uses other 2 columns in list in its formula.
Is there any way I can get those columns using CSOM?

Comment: You want formula or the comma separated column names ?

Comment: You can get the formula as string. Then you have to find column names by parsing the string.

Comment: I need to get the column names which are used in formula. Also if I get it from formula, how would it be done dynamically?